# Converting double to integers using R tidyverse

Tags: r, type-conversion, tidyverse, dplyr

Following [How to convert column types in R tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926705/how-to-convert-column-types-in-r-tidyverse?newreg=f8ae6a21191f45888ee3e8ad7c00afe4) I am trying to convert doubles (numeric) into integers.

For example, using the iris data:

```
iris1 <- iris %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length), integer)
```

The above throws an error, which I cannot understand despite following the recommended trouble shooting:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Petal.Length`.
ℹ `Petal.Length = (function (length = 0L) ...`
.x invalid 'length' argument
```

Using the same line of code to convert to factor and the results are fine:

```
iris1 <- iris %>%
mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length), factor)
class(iris1$Petal.Length)
```

Can someone explain to me the reason for the error and how I can convert to integer. Ideally I am looking for a solution friendly to the pipe operator `%>%`.

Comment: change the `integer` to `as.integer` ie explicit coercion to integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem you are running into is that `integer()` creates an integer-typed vector, which is just an empty place-holder for integers to go into. What you want is `as.integer()`, which takes an existing numeric vector and coerces each element into an integer. It's a minor distinction, so it's easy to miss. Here is your code with the fix implemented:

### A technically correct answer

```
iris1 <- iris %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length), as.integer) # note the AS.INTERGER()
```

### A more modern approach

You might be interested to know that `mutate_at()` has been superseded by the more modern `mutate(across(...)))` approach. Depending on your goals, you might prefer the more modern way to solve this problem with `dplyr`:

```
iris2 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(across(
    .cols = matches('Petal.Length'),
    .fns = ~ as.integer(.x)))
```

### Don't forget about rounding

Just a heads up, coercing something into an integer drops any decimal values, which is basically like **rounding down** every value to the nearest (lower) integer. You might want to round your numbers first, then coerce them to integer format, depending on your other goals for this code.

```
iris1 <- iris %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length), ~ as.integer(round(.x)))
```

OR

```
iris2 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(across(
    .cols = matches('Petal.Length'),
    .fns = ~ round(as.integer(.x))))
```

Comment: Thanks for this excellent and detailed answer. The suggested solution works perfectly. I'm new to the tidyverse workflow so the explanations of the newer mutate options are also very helpful.

Comment: It may be worthy mentioning across() can be combined with where() to subset the data to enter the function, as in `iris %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ as.integer(round(.x))))`

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad to have had the chance to help. If you feel like the answer met your needs, feel free to select it as the solution too (no pressure of course).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem trying to run "uncount" on a column that
had been converted from a percentage to an absolute number, so it was in effect an integer but still technically a double

```
# A tibble: 18 × 2
   MobileOS      OS_2010
   <fct>           <dbl>
 1 Android          1190
 2 BlackBerry OS    2013
 3 Brew                0
 4 iOS              5358
 5 LG                 52
 6 Linux               0
 7 Nintendo           79
 8 Nintendo 3DS        0
 9 Nokia Unknown       0
10 Other              77
11 Playstation       218
12 Samsung           174
13 Series 40           0
14 Sony Ericsson      43
15 SymbianOS         141
16 Unknown           433
17 webOS             117
18 Windows           105
```

Apparently you could get away with that in the old days

So I tried the older way to coerce the double to integer

```
df %<>%
  mutate_at(vars(OS_2010), as.integer) %>%
  print()
```

That worked, and the "uncount" worked

Then I reran the problem and used the modern way

```
df %<>%
  mutate(across(
    .cols = matches('OS_2010'),
    .fns = ~ as.integer(.x)))
```

That worked also.